# Include Custom Posts Type in Year/Month/Date Archive

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

I am looking for solution where I able to get all custom post types in year, month and date archive list. So it can be filters by anything either year, month or date. I am looking for function something like below which I am using to include CPT for authors

```
function custom_post_author_archive($query) {
    if ($query->is_author)
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('wp_plugin_review', 'png_gallery', 'post', 'news') );
    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_author_archive' );
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_author_archive');
```

Comment: It's tangential to your question, but instead of using remove_action in this case (which avoids affecting subsequent queries in the sidebar and stuff) you can just use is_main_query($query) at the start of the function. That will ensure it only fires on the "main" (first, core) query of the page and not others.

Comment: Appreciate and will try and get back to you.. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code simply adds post types to the query when on the author archive so to do the same with date archive simply replace `is_author` to `is_date` :

```
function custom_post_date_archive($query) {
    if ($query->is_date)
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('wp_plugin_review', 'png_gallery', 'post', 'news') );
    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_author_archive' );
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_date_archive');
```

Comment: Wonderful! perfect.. superb.. haha thanks a lot... working just like wanted.... :)