# WordPress search and date filter not working with custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I have a custom post type registered in my WordPress. Everything is working fine except Search and Filter functions are not working in admin. For example, I have posts from 2013 but when I select 2013 from filter drop-down, I get nothing.

Comment: What filter dropdown? Is this a feature of you theme?

Comment: Dates filter, default in WordPress

Comment: So the *Archives* widget?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include Custom Posts Type in Year/Month/Date Archive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62386/include-custom-posts-type-in-year-month-date-archive)

Comment: How (code?) did you register the custom post type?

Comment: Edited the question with code

Comment: @JacobPeattie this issue is post-listing page,

Comment: Are you using any `pre_get_posts` hooks in your theme that might be affecting things?  I've found that when the listing in the admin is screwed up, it's usually some other code snippet or plugin that is causing the issue.

Comment: @dkeeling, yes, this was the issue. Thank you very much, you saved me a lot of time. Can you post an answer so I can select it accepted for future visitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using any `pre_get_posts` hooks in your theme that might be affecting things? I've found that when the listing in the admin is screwed up, it's usually some other code snippet or plugin that is causing the issue.